# PHPMailer how to clear embedded images

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer in PHP and I have three emails addresses as recipients: one is gmail address, one is yahoo address, and one is another email address...

So because I am adding embedded images, I implemented in this way due for different behavior to different mailboxes:

```
foreach($email_to as $address) {
    
    $path = "../../images/myimage.png";
    $type_file = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    //$cid = md5($path);
    $cid = "logo_image";
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP(); 
    $phpmailer->ContentType = "text/html";
    $phpmailer->Host = "x.x.x.x";
    $phpmailer->Port = 25;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = false;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = false;
    $phpmailer->SMTPAutoTLS = false; 
    $phpmailer->From = "user@domain.biz";
    $phpmailer->FromName = "who";
    $phpmailer->Priority = 1;
    $phpmailer->AddCustomHeader("X-MSMail-Priority: High");
    $phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
    $phpmailer->Subject = "mail test"; 
    
    $phpmailer->AddAddress( trim($address[0]) );

    $heading_data = "....";
    
    $template_mail = "<table bgcolor='#73af27' border='1'>";
    $template_mail .= "<tr bgcolor='#73af27' style='width: 800px'><th style='border: 0.2em solid #004379; background-color: #73af27; width: 400px'><img src='cid:$cid' alt='my logo' border='0' width='95%' /></th><th cellpadding='10' style='text-align: right; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; color: white; border: 0.2em solid #004379; width: 400px'>".$heading_data."</th></tr>";
    $template_mail .= "</table>";
    
    $search = strtoupper(trim($address[0]));
    $key = "GMAIL";
    if( preg_match("/{$search}/i", $key) ) {
        $phpmailer->AddEmbeddedImage($path, $cid, "myimage.png", "base64", "image/png");
    } else {
        $phpmailer->AddEmbeddedImage($path, $cid, "myimage.png", "base64", "application/octet-stream");
    }
    
    //$phpmailer->Body = $template_mail;
    $phpmailer->msgHTML($template_mail);
    
    try {
        $phpmailer->Send();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        file_put_contents( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/test_errorinfo.log', print_r( $phpmailer->ErrorInfo . PHP_EOL, true ), FILE_APPEND);
    }
    
    $phpmailer->clearAllRecipients( );
    $phpmailer->clearAttachments();
    $phpmailer->smtpClose();    
}
```

the matter is if I send first mail to GMail then it attaches embedded as type image/png but if in next loop I send mail to Yahoo, it looks like it doesn't really clear any embedded image because I don't receive mail on Yahoo.. and viceversa.

I tried to `clearAttachments` but without success...

How I can manage to really clear embedded image so it can be sent to all emails with their properly embedded type?

Thanks to all in advance!!!
Cheers!

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. How can not receiving an email be the consequence of an embedded image? Not receiving an email is most commonly caused by the receiving mail server refusing to receive it.

Comment: hello @KIKOSoftware , I am asking because if I use `$phpmailer->AddEmbeddedImage($path, $cid, "myimage.png", "base64", "application/octet-stream");` without any if to change just the type of image I won't receive any email on GMail account but on Yahoo and office's mailbox ... With this if I receive on GMail account because it's the first element of the email array but when picking yahoo's email at next loop even if I change the type of image in addEmbedded image i won't receive mail on yahoo anyway...

Comment: I don't think the type of image in the email is the cause here. I can't see from which mail server you're sending these emails, but often the receiving mail servers use a spam filter that stops certain emails. Each spam filter is different, and this may cause the difference you see. You could read: [How Spam Filters Work](https://www.theseventhsense.com/blog/how-spam-filters-work-and-how-to-stop-emails-going-to-spam). This article is certainly not complete, but it gives you an idea of what I am talking about.

Comment: You are not creating a new instance for each mail, you are re-using the one you have already stored in $phpmailer. I don't know - will it automatically create a new connection in this case, after you closed the current one with `$phpmailer->smtpClose();`?

Comment: `$search = strtoupper(trim($address[0])); $key = "GMAIL"; if( preg_match("/{$search}/i", $key)` - not sure why you are upper-casing this, if you are then performing a match with the `i` flag for case insensitive. Plus, what is with the curly braces?

Comment: It's really unclear what the problem is here. `clearAttachments` does clear embedded images – it simply resets the internal `attachment` array. Also I've no idea why you would deliberately choose to use `application/octet-stream` as the MIME type for a PNG image – it will typically prevent it from being displayed at all.

Comment: Thanks all.... especially to @KIKOSoftware !!! Your suggestion about reading the article how spam filters work made the trick.. I put fixed `AddEmbeddedImage` image as `image/png` then I added also smtp TLS authentication so now all emails recipients accepts the mail I send !!!  +1 Rep for @KIKOSoftware

Comment: You're welcome. I've struggled myself for years to get mail delivered on behalf of my customers. It became more and more difficult. In the end I opted for [an external API service](https://sourceforge.net/software/smtp/) that does all the heavy lifting for me. Even with TLS/SPF/DKIM and the like, emails can still be rejected. One day everything is fine, and then boom, nothing gets through. Perhaps spam filters have become better lately, but I had to give up doing email myself.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thank you for the link for external api services... I'll go read too for external services and see.. thanks again...